# R how to convert NaN to zero in a large sparse matrix?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, nan

My sparse matrix TM is 244MB, when I try

```
TM[is.na(TM@x)]<- 0
```

it has error:"Error: cannot allocate vector of size 244.8 Gb"
So, is there any other method to convert NaN to zero?

also, I have another question:
how to row-wise normalized sparse matrix when one row is full of zeros?

thx!

Comment: you could try just updating the `TM@x` vector ; e.g. `TM@x[is.nan(TM@x)] <- 0` .Then probably want to drop the zeros e.g. `TM = drop0(TM)` (But to give a full answer it would be good if you added a small reproducible example to your question)

Comment: for your second question: this is not really a programming question per se. Rowwise normalization presumably means each row is divided by its sum. It's up to you to decide how you want to define the outcome of division of a vector of zeros by a scalar zero ...

Comment: @user20650 Thx! `TM@x[is.nan(TM@x)] <- 0` works well.

Comment: how about i want to do rowwise normalization when the rowsum of one row is not equal to zero, and not do normalization when the rowsum is equal to zero?